# img src to azure blob storage image not working from html tag

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I started playing with Azure blob storage and uploaded a few images. I also added a custom domain. So now if I use a browser and go to `http://images.example.com/some/fileName.jpg` I can see the image. But if I use this url in an `img` tag like so:

```
<img src="http://images.example.com/some/fileName.jpg" />
```

the image is broken. Any idea why?

### UPDATE

So far I've found out that if I use the original link in the tag it works fine:

```
<img src="http://example.blob.core.windows.net/images/some/fileName.jpg" />
```

So I guess the problem originates from the custom domain.
The content type is set to `image/jpg`

Comment: Broken how? 404? Is your container's security set to Public Blob or Public Container?

Comment: @evilSnobu I checked and its 200 OK, but the response content type is text/html for some reason. When I copy paste the url and go to it in another tab, the content type is image/jpeg. And yes it's public.

Comment: Can you share the actual URL of the image and also your code?

Comment: Have you set the ContentType of your image blob to "image/jpeg"?

Comment: @GauravMantri there is no code, just this img tag. its a public images cdn. I prefer to avoid sharing the actual url at the moment.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft Yes. The content type is image/jpg for the .jpg file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I narrowed it down to something wrong with the CNAME. I eventually just deleted the CNAME and the storage, and recreated them. Now it works. I'm not sure what exactly was wrong but it had something to do with the return MIME when tying to access the file via the custom domain. Thank you all for helping.

Comment: Good to know that.

Answer (score 0):

@ShiranDror, there is a exsiting answered SO thread [Getting broken images from blob storage in Azure websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343361/getting-broken-images-from-blob-storage-in-azure-websites) which is similar with yours.

The issue might be caused by the operation latency. Please try to set the start time of the operation for Blob storage client.

For C#, setting the `StartTime` for [`OperationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.operationcontext.aspx). And for Java, using the function [`setClientTimeInMs`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/OperationContext.html#setClientTimeInMs(long)) for `OperationContext`.

Comment: I don't think it's the correct answer since he said "So now if I use a browser and go to http://images.example.com/some/fileName.jpg I can see the image."

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft Yeah, I update my post. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT this is a public blob storage, there is no code behind this, just an html img tag that refers to the image cdn url. The url works fine if you use it directly, but fails when you use it inside the img tag

Comment: @ShiranDror Did you try the [`timeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179431.aspx) parameter for the url?